# Perl: Why is this pattern matching?

Tags: regex, perl

Why is the below pattern match is successful? Am I missing something?

```
$a="pattern";
if($a =~ /[0-9]*/){
   print "Contains\n";
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `*` quantifier matches 0 or more.  And the pattern does match exactly zero digits.

You might want to use `+` which would denote a match 1 or more times.

Quoting from `perldoc perlre`:

```
   Quantifiers

   The following standard quantifiers are recognized:

       *           Match 0 or more times
       +           Match 1 or more times
       ?           Match 1 or 0 times
       {n}         Match exactly n times
       {n,}        Match at least n times
       {n,m}       Match at least n but not more than m times
```

Comment: Silly me. Forgot the basic meaning of *. Thx!

Answer (score 6):

Using `*` as a quantifier means *zero* or more instances. In this case it is matching with zero at the position just before the `p` of the target string.

To match at least one digit use `+` quantifier instead.